# Parse JSON to file

Tags: c#, android, json

I writing app for Android and have Json parser

I parse it to string, but I need to parse it to file, .txt for example.

How I can do it?

Code:

```
 private async Task<JsonValue> FetchAsync(string url)
    {
        // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
                JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
                //dynamic data = JObject.Parse(jsonDoc[15].ToString);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());


                // Return the JSON document:
                return jsonDoc;
```

I Writing app on C#, Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter (filepath);
sw.Write(json);
sw.Close();
```

Comment: if my file is on root of project, what i need to write in filepath?

Comment: Yes just the filename